# Challenging scenario while implementing a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, data-loader, upsert, insert

I have a specific scenario which I feel is a bit challenging and I would like to ask people's views in this forum on what they think could be a solution

I have an custom object (employees__c) which stores employees record of a company. This employee data is uploaded using data loader into salesforce every day. The csv file has employees Name,emp id and status information.

I have a trigger on employees__c object which creates another object called log__c which is child of employee__c. This log__c just records the status of employee( Active or Inactive) and has field called incident which gets a value as "new employee" if employee has status Active OR "removed employee" if employee has status Inactive. This logic is written in trigger.

```
trigger Atrigger on employee__C( after insert, before update){

if(Trigger.isInsert){
// create log record with incident field value as new employee

}

if(Trigger.Isupdate){

// create log record and check if the status in inactive/active and create the //log accordingly

}

}
```

The challenge part: requirement -> The employees who are in Salesforce but not in the csv files that is uploaded using dataloader , should be made as "Inactive" in Salesforce and thereby there corresponding log with incident field value as employee removed should be created.

My thoughts: I can query all the existing employees in Salesforce in Isupdate trigger block and see if the existing employees is in trigger.new or not , if not then make them inactive else keep them active. But this can also make the employees as inactive who were just added in IsInsert trigger.

PS : Users can also manually change the employee record to active or inactive so that should also be covered in the trigger.

Any Solution or idea ?

Thanks

Comment: have you looked at enabling [field history tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en) for the logging? if so it would save you having to write a trigger for this

Comment: Yes I have explored that option. But for my requirement I need flexibility to record the logs so I choose do it this way. I need to create log every time something changes which is not related to employee too.

Comment: 'tis not really Community Etiquette to call in assistance from a specific user

Comment: Sorry! I will delete that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we want to distinguish record creation between data loader and User Interface we generally prefer to create a new boolean field on an object and set that field value as true while inserting data using dataloader and make that field as false from user interface.

```
trigger Atrigger on employee__C( after insert, before update){

if(Trigger.isInsert){
// create log record with incident field value as new employee

    if(employee__c.isBulkUpload){
         //set incident as inactive.
    }

}

if(Trigger.Isupdate){

// create log record and check if the status in inactive/active and create the //log accordingly
// check for

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I auto update isBulkUpload when I am editing a record with user interface?

Comment: What do you mean by auto update?

Comment: How do I set the boolean field - isBulkUpload as true or false based on datalaoder or field update?

Comment: Create new field amd make default value as false but while uploading add this field in csv and set value=true

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can make the existing employees in Salesforce who are not in csv as inactive ? There is status field on employee object which can have value active or inactive

Comment: yes you can do that. 1. write apex code and get all records in a list and inside for loop set inactive=true 2. Update list

Comment: Ok, if I do this way, how can I reset the boolean value to false again from true before the next csv file is loaded using dataloader.